# P class definition in Garey and Johnson's Computers and Intractability

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

I'm reading right now Computers and Intractability by Garey and Johnson. I've found the definition of PTIME complexity class a little strange. This is how it looks:

Let $\Sigma = \{ 0,1\}$. By $\Sigma^{*}$ we denote the set of all finite strings created from symbols from $\Sigma$. If a computation on a Deterministic Turing Machine with input $x \in \Sigma^{*}$ ends in $q_{y}$ (yes-state), it means that TM accepts this input. Language $L_{M}$ recognised by the machine $M$ is given by:

$L_{M} = \{ x \in \Sigma^{*} :$ $M$ accepts $x \}$.

Time complexity function is given by:

$T_{M} = max\{ m : $ there is an $x \in \Sigma^{*}$, with $|x| = n$, such that the computation of $M$ on input $x$ takes time $m$$\}$.

We call program $M$ a polynomial time DTM program if there exists a polynomial $p$ such that, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $T_{M}(n) \leq p(n)$.

Then they give such $P$ class definition:

$P = \{ L :$ there is a polynomial time DTM program $M$ for which $L=L_{M} \}$

---

Does this mean that their P complexity class contains only languages that are composed of yes-instances, i.e. languages recognised by $M$, consisted of $x$ strings such that $M$ always halts in accepting state for every of them as an input? What about input that also causes halting, but in rejecting state $q_{n}$? Shouldn't these be also in PTIME?

Do I understand this correctly? If yes, why they decided to define P class in such way?

P.S. Maybe that matters, I have the first edition of the book (1979).

Comment: Try also https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @lhf I've tried and I've received the answer there, thanks! In case anybody's interested: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85080/p-class-definition-in-garey-and-johnsons-computers-and-intractability/85084?noredirect=1#comment182414_85084